# Why wp_update_post return invalid post id

Tags: wordpress

I am getting an error with WordPress `wp_update_post()` function that says "Invalid post ID". Here is my code:

```
$current_item = 273;
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $current_item,
      'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
  );
$post_id = wp_update_post( $my_post, true );                          
if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried looking into the logs?

Answer (score 5):

Use `'import_id'`, not `'ID'`.

If there is no post at the ID you specify, `wp_update_post()` doesn't create a new one - it returns an error. In order to specify the ID of a new post use `'import_id' => $current_item`.

Note, though, that if there IS a post with that ID, `import_id` will cause a new post instead of an update. So if you want to EITHER make a new post with that ID OR update the post at that ID, you'll need an `if` statement to pick your key:

```
$newPostKey = (get_post_status($current_item)) ? 'ID' : 'import_id';
// If there's a post with an ID of $current_item, we'll use 'ID'.
// Otherwise, use 'import_id'.
```

Here's your shiny new code.

```
$current_item = 273;
$newPostKey = (get_post_status($current_item)) ? 'ID' : 'import_id';

$my_post = array(
    $newPostKey    => $current_item,
    'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
    'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
);
$post_id = wp_update_post( $my_post, true );
```

Comment: Note that this all applies to `wp_insert_post()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for this info @Brett, very useful indeed